# How to get refresh token using Microsoft Authentication Library (Msal) in android

Tags: android, single-sign-on

I am trying to sign in to my android application using Microsoft Single Sign on, using MSAL implemenation as provided [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android).

In onCreate

```
mApp = new PublicClientApplication(this.getApplicationContext(), API.CLIENT_ID, API.AUTHORITY);
```

When the user presses "Sign in with Microsoft" option, I call the method to acquire token as

```
mApp.acquireToken(this, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.msal_scopes), getAuthInteractiveCallback());
```

After handling redirect request in onActivityResult, I grab the authentication response at the callback as

```
private AuthenticationCallback getAuthInteractiveCallback() {
        return new AuthenticationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(AuthenticationResult authenticationResult) {
                /* Successfully got a token, use it to call a protected resource */
                accessToken = authenticationResult.getAccessToken();
                Log.d("AuthSuccess"," "+accessToken);
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(MsalException exception) {
                /* Failed to acquireToken */

                Log.d("AuthFail"," "+exception.getMessage());

                if (exception instanceof MsalClientException) {
                    /* Exception inside MSAL, more info inside MsalError.java */
                } else if (exception instanceof MsalServiceException) {
                    /* Exception when communicating with the STS, likely config issue */
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                /* User canceled the authentication */
            }
        };
    }
```

The problem is, `AuthenticationResult` object gives the `access token`, but not the `refresh token`. The object simply does not have refresh token as one of it's parameter. Do I need to further call another method to grab the refresh token as well? How does one get both access and refresh token from microsoft single sign on using MSAL?!

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the library is not exposing the refresh token:
https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android/issues/202

Comment: How do we access files from Sharepoint ? Does it work with the accesstoken we received from IAuthenticationResult object?